# Blazor Web Assembly CSS isolation doesn't work

Tags: css, .net-8.0, hosted-blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-css-isolation

I migrated my Blazor WASM app to .NET 8, and I realised that CSS is not working if I use it in `{component}.razor.css`.

I mean

File `Component.razor`:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="@AllResourcesResolver["navbar_inicio"]"> @AllResourcesResolver["navbar_inicio"] </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<style>
    .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        color: white;
    }
</style>
```

This CSS works, but if I put the same CSS into `{component}.razor.css`, it doesn't work.

File `Component.razor.css`:

```
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: white;
}
```

Makes no sense to me, any help is welcome!